# SetBillingAdress not working (prog) on quote

Tags: magento2, orders, quote, billing-address

I'm creating orders programmaticaly but my billings address are not updating.

I can set the shipping address that I want (another from the connected user) but the billing is still the one from the connected user.

See :

```
            $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customerTemp=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customerTemp->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customerTemp->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customerTemp->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $codeClient = $orderData["code_client"];
        //add items in quote
        $comment = $orderData["comment"];
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            //add products
        }

        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $billings = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();
        $this->shippingRate->setCode('flatrate_flatrate');
        $shippingAddress->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //shipping method
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->shippingRate);
        $quote->setCouponCode("")->collectTotals();
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
//        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $this->nice($quote->getBillingAddress()->getCity());
        die;
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by adding missing fields in my array  :

```
    $shippingAdress = array(
    "customer_address_id" => "",
    "prefix" => "",
    'firstname' => $prenom,
    "middlename" => "",
    'lastname' => $nom,
    'street' => $adresse,
    "company"=> "",
    'street' => array($adresse),
    'city' => $villeShipping,
    'country_id' => "FR",
    'region' => $paysShipping,
    'postcode' => $CPShipping,
    'telephone' => "",
    'fax' => "",
    "same_as_billing" => true,
    'save_in_address_book' => 0
);
```